# PyQt - Form does not submit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, spynner

I'm trying to submit a form using PyQt. I started out using it via Spynner but I've deconstructed that in my repl to just the raw PyQT calls themselves to try to debug the issue.

```
>>> obr.webframe.findAllElements('.qust input').toList()
[<PyQt4.QtWebKit.QWebElement object at 0xa343f7c>, <PyQt4.QtWebKit.QWebElement object at 0xa343fb4>]
>>> 
>>> elem = obr.webframe.findAllElements('.qust input').toList()[1]
>>> elem.setFocus()
>>> elem.evaluateJavaScript("this.click()")
```

And when that didn't work, I pulled this snippet from the method in Spynner that invokes a click event, which also didn't work:

```
>>> jscode =
"var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');e.initEvent( 'click', true, true );this.dispatchEvent(e);"
>>> 
>>> elem.evaluateJavaScript(jscode)
```

And then finally:

```
>>> obr.webframe.findFirstElement('form')
<PyQt4.QtWebKit.QWebElement object at 0xa34387c>
>>> obr.webframe.findFirstElement('form').evaluateJavaScript('this.submit();')
<PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant object at 0xa343f44>
>>>
```

In all cases, it instantly just returns. No form post is made. The form is normal:

```
>>> obr.webframe.findFirstElement('form').attribute('action')
PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'SubmitPage.aspx?g=d7a717c38&ust=72a0fc7b&nm=01f00&se=53')
>>> obr.webframe.findFirstElement('form').attribute('method')
PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'post')
```

If anybody has any thoughts or suggestions, I'd be SUPER appreciative. As you can see, I've been just grasping at straws here. Not my preferred debugging style...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go with the click solution, as this will ensure that if the page has some javascript code executed when the submit button is clicked, it will be called too. It can change or even add additional fields to the post data.
Generally the code you used is correct, try to start the javascript click event with this snippet:

```
elem = obr.webframe.findAllElements('.qust input').toList()[1]
js_click = """
           var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
           evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, false, false, false, false, 0, this);
           this.dispatchEvent(evt);
           """
elem.evaluateJavaScript(js_click)
```

Comment: Thanks andrean, I'll give this a shot today.

Comment: Still a no-go. It's very strange to me. The page does have a simple onsubmit event listener that gets fired-off. I'm sure it's returning "True" and I also tried removing it outright. 

Also strange is that there's code on the page that calls a 3 second setTimeout() and the function passed to it never fires. Without better knowing PyQt I can't make sense of whether these 2 things are connected.

Comment: Could you show a link to that page, if it's public?
Also, if the setTimeout is called from the onclick or onsubmit event handlers, it is possible that the normal event bubbling is stopped inside the event handler, and settimeout calls a delayed request, which callback may change the content or do another request.

Also a possibility that the js code does some data validation when the submit button is clicked, and the data does not pass that validation, so the request is never initiated.

Comment: Andrean, I can't share the URL. I'm reverse-engineering to give our users a way to export their data from a service that recently went hostile on our data import. 

The setTimeout thing is very strange to me. There is a function I am calling using evaluateJavascript(). The function is called fine. In the function it does a setTimeout(3000). That timeout never fires. But I can manually call the function passed to setTimeout and it works fine. Very strange to me.

Comment: I assume the rest of the python code is correct right?so the app's event loop is running, the webview's loadFinished signal is connected to a function which will read the result?
could you follow with firebug's "Net" panel what happens when you click on the submit button? Is a request made immediately, and another one after 3 seconds, or just after 3 seconds or just immediately after clicking?
If there's an immediate request after clicking, and it returns a result before setTimeout starts another one(if it does), loadFinished will be emitted without waiting for the other request to start.

Comment: This is the sort of probing I was hoping to get some help with. PyQt is complex, and I've interacted with it via Spynner initially. I will look into the loadFinished callback, that seems promising. Thanks again!!

Comment: If you haven't used the loadFinished signal till now, that could solve the problem, as it's an async library, after you execute the javascript code, the python code won't block until the result arrives, but will just continue with the execution.

Comment: SUCCESS! As I mentioned, I've got a stripped-down hacked-up version of Spynner 2.1 as my starting point. The code does have a callback set for loadFinished. But I followed it backwards and realized that after the form submit button is clicked, my code returns instantly and moves-on. The solution was to call QApplication.processEvents() in a while loop until the POST is complete. 

Thanks for your expertise and help here!